# Reading Deleted or Update Value from the Open Transaction

Tags: t-sql

I trying to open the transaction and then delete one record now i need to insert the deleted record into event table. The problem is i can't see the result because it has been deleted.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[TestData] ( @clientid bigint ) As
Begin 
    print ''abc''
    insert into Client_Event_Log values ( getdate(),0,@clientid,100,''B0AE3162-671C-E211-AF2A-00155D051024'',NULL)



    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

        Delete from access_types    -- There is only record in the table.

        8559230 abc 101 0   2010-01-01 10:25:25.000

        select * from access_types  -- cann't see the deleted record even before the session.

        DECLARE @cGTAEventLog bigint
        select @cGTAEventLog=Access_Type_Id from access_types 
    
        exec TestData @cGTAEventLog   -- Now i am passing 8559230 to the SP to insert into event   
               table but it has been delete before so can't insert NULL

        Commit Tran
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        --Error message
        PRINT 'Error: ' + 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR,ERROR_NUMBER()) + ' - ' + 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR,ERROR_SEVERITY()) + ' - ' + 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR,ERROR_STATE()) + ' - ' + 
            ERROR_MESSAGE() + 
        ' Raise Error occurred at line ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ERROR_LINE())
    END CATCH
END
```

I need to find a way to access the data after deleting so i can insert into a event table.

Comment: Have you tried inserting the record *before* you delete it?  Since you're in a transaction, it doesn't matter what order you do it in, they either both will succeed or fail together.

Comment: yeah that will work but i need it after deletion. I can have the same situation for update or insert.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use the `output clause` to access the virtual 'deleted' table and park its contents in a table variable. Something like the following

```
DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE (ID INT, ......)

DELETE
FROM access_types
OUTPUT Deleted.ID,... INTO @TmpTable 

select * from @TmpTable
```